# Calculating the average of requests from log file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have logs from my API in a CSV file, and I'm trying to find out the average of requests clients send to each endpoint every 10 minutes.
the file is containing the following columns: id, timestamp, caller_ip, call_path, endpoint_path, method,status_code

I have the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"logs")
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df[df['status_code'].between(200, 299)]
grouped = df.groupby(['endpoint_path', pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='10min')])
avg_requests = grouped['caller_ip'].nunique().groupby('endpoint_path').sum() / grouped.size().groupby('endpoint_path').count()
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'endpoint_path': avg_requests.index, 'avg_requests': avg_requests.values})
```

But instead, I'm getting the average of unique clients who sends requests to an endpoint.

where is the problem in the code?
what should I do instead?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the issue in your code lies in the calculation of the average requests per endpoint.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("logs.csv")
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df[df['status_code'].between(200, 299)]

grouped = df.groupby(['endpoint_path', pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='10min')])
avg_requests = grouped['caller_ip'].nunique().groupby('endpoint_path').mean()  # Use mean() instead of sum() / count()

result_df = pd.DataFrame({'endpoint_path': avg_requests.index, 'avg_requests': avg_requests.values})
print(result_df)
```

Instead of using `grouped.size().groupby('endpoint_path').count()`, you can simply use `grouped['caller_ip'].nunique().groupby('endpoint_path').mean()` to calculate the average number of unique `caller_ip` per `endpoint_path` within each 10-minute interval.

When you want to construct the `result_df`, use `avg_requests.values` instead of `avg_requests` to extract the average values correctly.

Comment: Thats the problem,, you spot it, I'm trying to calculate the average requests users sending to an endpoint in 10 minutes time frame. You know how should I do it?